# k8s exec command terminated but the remote command does not

Tags: kubernetes, exec, sigterm

I am using k8s remote exec command to run a http server (via `cmd`). When the host program terminated (Ctrl+C), the remote command still running at the remote container.

How to terminate the remote command `cmd` also? Many thanks.

This is part of the k8s remote exec code:

```
remoteExecute(ctx context.Context, pod *k8sCore.Pod, containerName string, cmd []string,
    ioIn io.Reader, ioOut, ioErr io.Writer, tty bool,
) error {
    req := kClientSet.CoreV1().RESTClient().Post().
        Resource("pods").
        Name(pod.GetName()).
        Namespace(pod.GetNamespace()).
        SubResource("exec").
        VersionedParams(&k8sCore.PodExecOptions{
            Container: containerName,
            Command:   cmd,
            Stdin:     ioIn != nil,
            Stdout:    ioOut != nil,
            Stderr:    ioErr != nil,
            TTY:       tty,
        }, scheme.ParameterCodec)

    executor, err := remotecommand.NewSPDYExecutor(s.kRestCfg, "POST", req.URL())
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("new spdy executor: %w", err)
    }

    // run the command
    err = executor.StreamWithContext(ctx, remotecommand.StreamOptions{
        Stdin:  ioIn,
        Stdout: ioOut,
        Stderr: ioErr,
        Tty:    tty,
    })

    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("stream with context: %w", err)
    }

    return nil
}
```

The context captured signal correct already

```
    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(ctx)

    c := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    // Notify the signal channel for SIGINT (Ctrl+C) and SIGTERM (termination)
    signal.Notify(c, syscall.SIGINT, syscall.SIGTERM)

    go func() {
        <-c
        cancel()
    }()
```

Comment: What leads to this code path, rather than just creating a new Deployment and Service to run the HTTP server?  In Kubernetes especially, I'd avoid using exec-type commands for anything other than very short-term debugging.

Comment: Can you try running the Ctrl+D command after Ctrl+C. Let me know if this helps

Comment: hi @DavidMaze, you are correct, this is part of the debugging program. I am aware that this is short term session. Though I still want to shutdown the debugging program correctly

Comment: hi @FariyaRahmat thanks for the suggestion, but it doesn't work for me, the remote process still running